# MySQL query with INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

So i have a database with some tables. Now i want a query that gets data from 3 tables. First lets see what the databases are

```
omschrijvingVoorraad
-ID             1
-userID         1
-omschrijvingID 6
-min            4

omschrijving
-ID             6
-omschrijving   Cola (blikje 330ml)

voorraad
-ID             20
-userID         1
-omschrijvingID 6
-aantal         2
```

Now i want to make a query that will show the next line:

**Cola (blikje 330ml)** Aantal **2** minmaal **4**

I searched around and came up with below but it is not working. It doesn't give an error but just an empty result

```
$queryOm="SELECT omschrijvingVoorraad.ID, omschrijvingID, omschrijving, vAantal, min
        FROM omschrijvingVoorraad
        LEFT JOIN omschrijving ON omschrijving.ID = omschrijvingVoorraad.omschrijvingID
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT omschrijvingID vid, SUM( aantal ) vAantal  
            FROM voorraad WHERE userID='$userID' )  p ON vid = omschrijvingVoorraad.omschrijvingID
        WHERE userID='$userID'
        LIMIT $offset, $perPage";
```

Where offcourse the $offset and $perPage are being defined earlier in the code.

So can anyone tell me where I went wrong? What should I change to get the correct result?

Comment: Output the query and see if it works on the DB directly. Better of narrowing down if it is a PHP or mysql issue.

Comment: thanks for the sugestion chris85. however in phpmyadmin it also gave an empty result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to your schema and your expected result seem you need this query

```
select a.ID, a.omschrijvingID, b.omschrijving, sum(c.aantal), a.min
from omschrijvingVoorraad as a
inner join omschrijving as b on a.omschrijvingID = b.ID
inner join voorraad as c on a.omschrijvingID = c.omschrijvingID
group by a.ID, a.omschrijvingID, b.omschrijving, a.min
```

Comment: in the table voorraad there can be multiple results with the same omschrijvingID so i need to sum those up. I saw somewhere that you need a query inside a query for that?

Comment: I have update the answer .. i thnk should  be enough sum and group by

Comment: thanks this is indeed what is was looking for :) there are 3 typos but can't edit it though 4th line pn should be on last line missing 'a' befor the .ID and a comma to much at the end. for the people who also has a problem and find this awnser

Comment: I have update the answer correcting the typo .. thanks